# How to multiple sorting with jQuery Isotop?

Tags: sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm using jQuery isotope from there: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

There is a way to sort with multiple types?

For example: moving all green and blue boxes to the top of the container?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can sort for multiple types, [see this sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/3nY9V/). The [documentation for sorting is here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html). All you need is to make green or blue a data-category on each div. Or, you could use a class also. See [it here](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/5UwXn/) how to use the data-category for sorting. It's that simple. And another one [is well explained here](http://www.designbysweet.co.uk/blog_resources/isotope/). Now, you need just a bit of programming to adapt it for your case. But, again, it's all in the original's sorting documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what you show me its a combination of filter. Using your example on fiddle, what I want is to put red and blue boxes in first of all box with keeping other color in the end of the container.

Comment: I think you definitely don't understand what I want... but thanks anyway.

Comment: Before jumping to accusations and premature conclusions, you should first provide the code you have tried - an online sandbox, jsfiddle - or some other online sample showing and explaining exactly what you are after.

If you want to sort so that matching items are lined up after one another (first all greens, then all blues, then something else...) you simply sort for two or more data-categories or two or more item properties. It is easily understood from the documentation and fiddles how that's to be done.